# SlicePipe Angular funcion

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to create a slice that will be sorted, but slice does not communicate with setCurrentPage (ts)

html

```
*ngFor="let item of galleries | searchGalleries : searchValue | slice:start:end; trackBy:item?.id"
```

ts

```
  setCurrentPage(page = 0) {
    this.limit = 3;
    this.currentPage = page;
   this.start = this.currentPage * this.limit;
    this.end = this.start + 3;
  }
```

Comment: Where do you call setCurrentPage()?

Comment: In the .html
<div class="row" (onload)="setCurrentPage()">

Comment: but (onload) doesn't work in angular